# Selenium can not open opensea.io

Tags: python, selenium

When I'm trying to open opensea.io with selenium it's giving Cloudfare captcha, even if I solve the captcha the captcha page is not redirecting to opensea.io

Update: Installing vpn solved this but there must be other ways.

```
driver.get("https://opensea.io")
```

Error screenshot given below.

[cloudfare error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhDIe.png)

Comment: Code look correct. Fixed time of your computer and restsrt.

Comment: Cloudflare is designed to prevent scripts exactly like yours from accessing websites that don't want want to be accessed by browser automation software

Answer (score 2):

**Edited:**

There might be several reasons that are possibly causing this kind of problem:

1. Cloudflare blocked your I.P. Try using a new I.P. through a proxy (or VPN, Another ISP), and see if it works or not. (https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cant-bypass-cloudflare-captcha/200335/8)
2. Depending on Selenium versions and editions, it could explicitly tell the browser that it is a bot and allow the websites to know it is Selenium, so Cloudflare then blocks the request.
3. The browser is the problem. Try a different browser like Firefox.
4. Cloudflare or the website you are trying to reach cares about special cookies that are not available on a Selenium new browser (This was my wild guess, but it's not the case).

P.S.: I have tried to connect to this URL (https://opensea.io), and interestingly, it worked fine for me.
Here is some information about the environment I performed this action on:

- *Operation System:* CentOS 7, Linux
- *Selenium Standalone Version:* 4.0.0
- *Java Version:* jre-8u311-linux-x64
- *The browser I used:* **Firefox**

Comment: It's opening with my chrome, but when i try to open with selenium it doenst work.

Comment: Are you running your selenium on a separate server? If yes, then the IP of that server is blocked. But if you are running selenium locally (they are on the same machine and have the same IP), it's really odd.

Comment: I'm running locally, I have no problem solving captcha but the page stays on the captcha page even after completing captcha, It does to redirect to opensea website

Comment: Interesting. Is it the case even if you try opening the page in incognito mode? If it won't work on incognito mode, it means that Cloudflare is analyzing your cookies and allows you to enter the page accordingly.

Comment: It open easily on my chrome or firefox browser, it doesn't even ask for captcha, but with selenium driver it doesn't work, even after solving captcha.

Comment: Also, I just tried opening this URL on my selenium. It worked fine for me.

Comment: Have you tried opening it through incognito mode? (without selenium)

Comment: Yes it works in incognito mode also without selenium

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).